# Viewport/Client Width in a Lightning App

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, mobile

I'm working on a Lightning App that we want to display properly on mobile, but I'm having trouble with the viewport width when using a mobile device.

Here's my proof-of-problem app:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <div style="background: grey">
        foo
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

If I view that on a desktop browser window of width 1200, and check document.documentElement.clientWidth in the javascript console, then I get the result 1200. As expected. Then, resize that window to 375px, and try again: I still get document.documentElement.clientWidth at 375px.

Then, tell Chrome to simulate an iPhone 6. This makes the actual window 375px, but document.documentElement.clientWidth reports 980px.

I found some old discussion of this, saying the problem is the viewport settings and suggesting the use of JS to inject the following header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Obviously, we can't really inject things like that with Locker Service.

Anything I try to do with responsive layouts on mobile is going to be ineffective if Lightning forces the viewport to be at least 980px.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the clientWidth issue using chrome simulator as described in the question.

So I tried adding the meta tag to the Lightning app directly and logged the `clientWidth` and it is properly returning the width based on the viewport when tested with the chrome simulator.

**myApp.app:**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
    <div style="background: grey">
        foo
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.logwidth}">logwidth</button>

</aura:application>
```

**myAppController.js**

```
({
    logwidth : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        console.log(document.documentElement.clientWidth )
    }
})
```

Comment: Ha! Now that you've said it, it seems like the obvious solution. Which is the best kind of solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lightning:flexipageRegionInfo

[Make Your Lightning Page Components Width-Aware with lightning:flexipageRegionInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_width_aware.htm)