# Any way to scale (zoom) whole Lightning component based Community pages?

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, slds, responsive-design

We have an internal debate that for a specific Community application, the standard font sizes are too small. So the ideal would be to scale the whole page of content whatever namespace the content is from. See e.g. [Viewport/Client Width in a Lightning App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176291/viewport-client-width-in-a-lightning-app) or [Responsive Web Design - The Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp), including the `initial-scale` zoom level.

But I doubt this is possible i.e. that there is any place to inject the `<meta .../>` and that the various components will all play ball. Have you succeeded in this sort of scaling/zooming?

**PS**

Thanks stackasaur for your suggestion. Good to know that mechanism exists in Communities. For my, case, the result I got was that my input - the first line here - was prepended to some default output - the second line here - and had no effect at least on desktop Chrome:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=3.0"/>
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" name="viewport"/>
```

Comment: In the community builder, you can edit the <head> in the configuration. Try adding your meta data and see what happens.

Comment: have you tried using lightning out and a VF Page to set the meta within a head tag on the VF Page instead?

Comment: Most of the slds styles use "rem" as units, so maybe if you change the default font size on the <body> it should scale everything accordingly